# NASM: segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm new to assembly and I've been trying to learn through random problems. Im using nasm 64 bit on a linux machine. I've been trying to generate the fibonacci sequence. However I get a segmentation fault(core dumped) error when I run my executable.

```
section .data

    input db 2

section .bss

    fib resb 128

section .text

_start:

    mov rax, 1
    mov rcx, 1
    mov rdx, fib
    mov rdx, 1
    inc rdx
    mov rbx, 0

    call _fibLoop
    call _fibPrint

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

_fibLoop:

    mov [rdx], rax
    inc rdx
    add rcx, rax
    push rcx
    mov rcx, [rax]
    pop rax
    inc rbx
    cmp rbx, [input]
    jne _fibLoop
    ret
```

I know the call to _fibPrint is not the issue cause it does virtually nothing. I assume the way I am writing to my reserved memory is flawed. However Ive been able to do this similarly in the past so I'm lost on whats wrong.

Comment: Have you attached a debugger and stepped through the code? Where does it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of your initialization, you have this sequence:

```
mov rdx, fib
mov rdx, 1
inc rdx
```

This will leave `rdx` with the value `2`, and not the offset of a buffer to hold your numbers.  Then, at the start of `_fibLoop`, you write to it with

```
mov [rdx], rax
```

This will try to access memory that you cannot access, resulting in the segmentation fault.

I think removing the extra two lines after `mov rdx,fib` will fix that crash, letting you move on to debugging the other bugs using GDB or whatever other debugger you like.

(Like that `inc rdx` in `_fibLoop` only advances the pointer by 1 byte, but you're doing 8 byte stores.  And that `input` is also only 1 byte, but you're doing an 8-byte load there, too.)

Comment: how would I make rdx equal the offset then?

Comment: @IanMacpherson: you're already doing that (inefficiently) with `mov rdx, fib`.  Just remove the instructions that overwrite RDX right after that!  In x86-64, the normal way to put static addresses in registers is a RIP-relative LEA, like `lea rdx, [rel fib]`.  Or as an optimization for Linux non-PIE executables, `mov edx, fib` to use a 32-bit absolute immediate.

Comment: won't mov rdx, fib point to the beginning of fib, meaning if I write it will override whatever is there?

Comment: I see what I've misunderstood thank you for your help.